# Adding Color to Sankey Diagram in rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts, sankey-diagram

I've created a sankey diagram in rCharts but have one question. How do I add color? I'd like to represent each node with a different color so it's easier to vizualize the paths, instead of just seeing the same grey lines connecting everything.  Code and output below:

```
    require(rCharts)
    require(rjson)

    x = read.csv('/Users/<username>/sankey.csv', header=FALSE)

    colnames(x) <- c("source", "target", "value")

    sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()

    sankeyPlot$set(
     data = x,
     nodeWidth = 15,
     nodePadding = 10,
     layout = 32,
     width = 500,
     height = 300,
     units = "TWh",
     title = "Sankey Diagram"
    )

    sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey')

    sankeyPlot
```

Here is what my chart looks like

[image]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

not sure what colors you want, but if you have installed the newer `rCharts` with `devtools::install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")`, here is how you might color based on the source value with a [demo here](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?79350d7475a5709b051e).

```
require(rCharts)
require(rjson)

x = read.csv('/Users/<username>/sankey.csv', header=FALSE)

colnames(x) <- c("source", "target", "value")

sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()

sankeyPlot$set(
 data = x,
 nodeWidth = 15,
 nodePadding = 10,
 layout = 32,
 width = 500,
 height = 300,
 units = "TWh",
 title = "Sankey Diagram"
)

sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey')

sankeyPlot$setTemplate(
  afterScript = "
<script>
// to be specific in case you have more than one chart
d3.selectAll('#{{ chartId }} svg path.link')
  .style('stroke', function(d){
    //here we will use the source color
    //if you want target then sub target for source
    //or if you want something other than gray
    //supply a constant
    //or use a categorical scale or gradient
    return d.source.color;
  })
 //note no changes were made to opacity
 //to do uncomment below but will affect mouseover
 //so will need to define mouseover and mouseout
 //happy to show how to do this also
 // .style('stroke-opacity', .7) 
</script>
")

sankeyPlot
```

If you wanted to use a `d3.scale.category??()` to provide your color, I assume you would want to also similarly color the node rectangle.  Here is one example of changing the color for both the node and the link.

```
sankeyPlot$setTemplate(
  afterScript = "
<script>
  var cscale = d3.scale.category20b();

  // to be specific in case you have more than one chart
  d3.selectAll('#{{ chartId }} svg path.link')
    .style('stroke', function(d){
      //here we will use the source color
      //if you want target then sub target for source
      //or if you want something other than gray
      //supply a constant
      //or use a categorical scale or gradient
      //return d.source.color;
      return cscale(d.source.name);
    })
   //note no changes were made to opacity
   //to do uncomment below but will affect mouseover
   //so will need to define mouseover and mouseout
   //happy to show how to do this also
   // .style('stroke-opacity', .7)
  d3.selectAll('#{{ chartId }} svg .node rect')
    .style('fill', function(d){
      return cscale(d.name)
    })
    .style('stroke', 'none')
</script>
")

sankeyPlot
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Only thing I'm unclear on is how to change to specific colors.  I tried redefining the color variable, giving it d3.scale.category10() for example, but that didn't work for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: added more code at end of the answer to show how to custom color everything based on a d3 color scale