# rCharts Sankey Diagram not plotting

Tags: r, rcharts, sankey-diagram

Using the code from this [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412223/adding-color-to-sankey-diagram-in-rcharts) [demo2](http://rcharts.io/viewer/?79350d7475a5709b051e#.U_VMq_ldWSo) I am unable to view the plot. I am using rStudio and all I see in the "viewer" window is the url

http://timelyportfoli.github.ip/rCharts_d3_sankey//layouts/chart.html

I must be doing something wrong, but I am not getting any errors or warnings, and cannot find the solution.

```
require(rCharts)
require(plyr)

gallery <- read.csv(
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AovoNzJt5GetdEhQVDgyYXpJMnZ2M2J2YmtvX0I5Snc&output=csv",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

gallery.use <- gallery[,c("technology","visualizationType","documentType","author")]
colnames(gallery.use) <- rep("column",4)

gallery.edge <- rbind(
  gallery.use[,1:2],
  gallery.use[,2:3],
  gallery.use[,3:4],
  deparse.level=1
)

colnames(gallery.edge) <- c("source","target")

gallery.edge <- ddply(gallery.edge,~source+target,nrow)

colnames(gallery.edge) <- c("source","target","value")

#verify that no source = target
#or will get stuck in infinite loop
gallery.edge[which(gallery.edge[,1]==gallery.edge[,2]),]



gallery.edge$source <- as.character(gallery.edge$source)
gallery.edge$target <- as.character(gallery.edge$target)
sankeyPlot2 <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot2$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/')
sankeyPlot2$set(
  data = gallery.edge,
  nodeWidth = 15,
  nodePadding = 10,
  layout = 32,
  width = 960,
  height = 500
)


sankeyPlot2$setTemplate(
  afterScript = "
  <script>
  // to be specific in case you have more than one chart
  d3.selectAll('#{{ chartId }} svg path.link')
  .style('stroke', function(d){
  //here we will use the source color
  //if you want target then sub target for source
  //or if you want something other than gray
  //supply a constant
  //or use a categorical scale or gradient
  return d.source.color;
  })
  //note no changes were made to opacity
  //to do uncomment below but will affect mouseover
  //so will need to define mouseover and mouseout
  //happy to show how to do this also
  // .style('stroke-opacity', .7) 
  </script>
  ")

sankeyPlot2
```

Comment: Added code. Copied and pasted from demo link above.

Comment: Strange, the example looks good here. My `sessionInfo()` says _R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), plyr_1.8.1, rCharts_0.4.5_ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. The package was installed incorrectly.